# Use metro window with visual studio extension

Tags: microsoft-metro, visual-studio-extensions, mahapps.metro, modern-ui

I am developing a **Visual Studio Extension**. It shows a tool window. The element is s user control which is automatically generated. I want to use a window instead of user control. The reason behind this is, I want to use Metro style window. for which I need a window control derived from **`MetroWindow`** class. But as the tool window is generated using a windows control, I am unable to apply metro style to it as it is not a window and I am unable to derive it form metro window class.

Comment: You can put the nested MahApps resources in the UserControl too.

Comment: I gave that a try but after i insert the MahApps control tags in xaml code, it throws and error "file or assembly could not be loaded"